# Test async function without setTimeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, angular-promise

I would like it if someone can help me to test this function without using the setTimeout that I am using IN THE TEST FILE. after doing a lot of research I was able to make it go, but that setTimeout is a time bomb.
I probed with jasmine-promises and a thousand different ways but none of them worked.

**service:**

```
angular.module('moduloPrueba', [])
  .factory('asincronico', function($q) {

  return {
    tes:tes,
  };


  function tes(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    setTimeout(function () {

      deferred.resolve(79);
    }, 50);

    // Return the deferred promise
    return deferred.promise;
  }

});
```

**jasmine test:**

```
describe('description', function () {
  var asi;
  var root;
  var res;

  beforeEach(function () {
    module('moduloPrueba');
    inject(function (asincronico, $rootScope) {
      root = $rootScope;
      asi = asincronico;
    })
  });

  it('should ', function (done) {
    asi.tes().then(function (resp) {
      res = resp;
      done();
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
      root.$digest();
      expect(res).toEqual(79);
      expect(res).not.toEqual(123);
    }, 200);

  });

});
```

Comment: So set it to 0.

Comment: if i do that it throws me "Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL."

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$timeout` service instead of `setTimeout`.

```
angular.module('moduloPrueba', [])
    .factory('asincronico', function ($q, $timeout) {

        return {
            tes: tes
        };


        function tes() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $timeout(function () {

                deferred.resolve(79);
            }, 50);

            // Return the deferred promise
            return deferred.promise;
        }

    });
```

Then call `$timeout.flush()` in your test to wait for the timeout to finish, followed by a `$rootScope.$digest()` to get the promise to resolve. You also will not need a `done` callback anymore since this will run synchronously.

```
describe('description', function () {
    var asi;
    var root;
    var timeout;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('moduloPrueba');
        inject(function (asincronico, $rootScope, $timeout) {
            root = $rootScope;
            asi = asincronico;
            timeout = $timeout;
        })
    });

    it('should ', function () {

        asi.tes().then(function (resp) {
            expect(resp).toEqual(79);
            expect(resp).not.toEqual(123);
        });

        timeout.flush();
        root.$digest();
    });

});
```

Comment: it works. what if a have something to resolve, but not wrapped in a $timeout function. example a "search in a database".

Comment: Assuming that the "search in the database" is some kind of service that is injected like the `$timeout` service, then you can inject that service in your test and use [spyOn(object, method)](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies) to mock the behavior.

Comment: what I want is to use a function that I have in a service and pass a query and test that data returned.

Comment: Update your question with the relevant code or create a new one, I do not have enough context to provide an answer.